# JSON Hyper-Schema: Correct way to extract instance IDs for application URLs

Tags: json, rest, flask-potion

Using JSON Hyper-Schema via [Flask-Potion](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Potion/0.7.2), I have an API that returns a list of species found at `/api/species`.  It returns something like this:

```
[
{
    "$uri": "/api/species/1",
    "latin_name": "danio rerio",
    "name": "zebrafish"
}
]
```

For my web frontend, I'd like `/species/1` to be the user facing URL that obtains its data for display purposes from `/api/species/1`. This user facing URL has nothing to do with the underlying API except it makes sense to map the IDs since how else will I format my user facing URLs?  So when I have a list of species that should link to their respective species pages, how to I form `/species/1`? Since the $uri I get from my API is the API uri, am I supposed to parse this string to extract "`1`" or is there a more elegant solution that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches to do this in Potion. The choice of `"$uri"` as object identifier is not specific to JSON HyperSchema, it is simply the default configuration option in Potion.

If you wish to use the `"$uri"` field, you have to parse it to retrieve the ID. But you can also tell Potion to instead return an `"$id"` field with a numeric ID using `Meta.id_field_class`  [documented here](http://potion.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#meta-class-attributes).

```
class SpeciesResource(ModelResource):
    # ...
   class Meta:
      id_field_class = fields.Integer
```

You can combine this with a `"$type"` field by setting `Meta.include_type = True`

Generally, if you want to add a read-only field of any type to your resource, just specify it in the schema:

```
class SpeciesResource(ModelResource):
    # ...
    class Schema:
        id = fields.Integer(io='r')
```